# Holiday Calender Algorithm, c++

Tags: c++, class, calendar

I need to make a calender that calculates the exact date for each major holiday of US, so the date for some of those holidays are different every year. 
Here are the major functions I used:

```
   static int isLeap(int year) {

            return ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0));// returns true if the given year is a leap year and false otherwise
        }

        // returns the day code the the new year day of the given year

        static int get_day_code(int year) {
            return (year + (year - 1) / 4 - (year - 1) / 100
                + (year - 1) / 400) % 7;
        }
        // overloading get_day_code that returns the day code of the specific day

        static int get_day_code(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            int dayforyear = get_day_code(year);
            Date tmp(month, day, year);
            int doy = tmp.dayOfYear() - 1;
            int daycode = (dayforyear + doy) % 7;
            return daycode;

        }
        //returns the day code of a given date , the day code  = 0 means sunday , 1 means monday


       int Date::dayOfWeek()
    {
        int dayofyear = this->dayOfYear() - 1;
        int firstdayofyear = Date::get_day_code(*this->year);
        dayofyear += firstdayofyear;
        return dayofyear % 7;

    }
    int Date::dayOfYear()
    {
        int doy = 0;
        int leap = isLeap(*year);
        for (int i = 1; i<*month; i++)
        {
            doy += daysInMonth[leap][i];
        }
        doy += *day;
        return doy;


    }

Holiday algorithms: 
  // MLK day third monday of January
Date MLKDay(int yr)
{

    int days = Date::get_day_code(yr);
    int result = 0;
    if(days>1)
        result=1+2*7+7-days+1;
    else
        result=1+7*2+1-days;

    return Date(1, result, yr);

    // the third Monday of January each year
}

Date Valentine(int yr)
{

    return Date(2, 14, yr);
}

Date PresidentDay(int yr)
{  // 3rd monday of Febraury

    int p;
    int result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + 31)%7 ;
    if(result>1)
        p=1+2*7+7-result+1;
    else
        p=1+7*2+1-result;




    return Date(2, p, yr);
    // put your code here

}
Date StPatrick(int yr)
{  //mar 17


    Date temp(3, 17, yr);
    return temp;
}

Date AprilFool(int yr)
{
    return Date(4, 1, yr);
}

Date MayDay(int yr)
{  // May ist

    Date tmp(5, 1, yr);
    return tmp;
}
Date MotherDay(int yr)
{  // 2nd sunday in may
    // put your code here
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<5; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result, M;
    result = ( Date::get_day_code(yr)+days) % 7;
    if(result>0)
        M=1+7+7-result;
    else
        M=8;

    cout<<result;
    return Date(5, M, yr);

}
Date MemorialDay(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<6; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int m;
    int result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + days-1) % 7; //31st may
    if(result>1)
        m=31-(result-1);
    else
        m=31-(6+result);
    return Date(5, m, yr);


    // function that returns a Date object which is the date for Memoriial day of year yr
    //the last monday of May
    // put your code here

}

Date FatherDay(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<6; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result, F;
    result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + days) % 7;
    if (result> 0)
        F = 1+7*2+7-result;
    else 
        F = 1+7*2;
    return Date(6, F, yr);





    // 3rd sunday in June
    // put your code here
}

Date IndependenceDay(int yr)
{  // July 4

    Date tmp(7, 4, yr);
    return tmp;
}


Date Labor(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<9; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result, L;
    result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + days) % 7;
    if(result>1)
        L=1+7-result+1;
    else
        L=1+1-result;

    return Date(9, L, yr);


    //first monday of sep
    // function that returns a Date object which is the date for Labor day of  the year yr
    // put your code here
}

Date Columbus(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result = (Date::get_day_code(yr)+days ) % 7;
    int C = 0;
    if(result>1)
        C=1+7+7-result+1;
    else
        C=1+7+1-result;

    return Date(10, C, yr);




    // second monday of october
    // put your code here
}

Date Halloween(int yr)
{
    Date tmp(11, 1, yr);    // november 1st, a day after Halloween
    return --tmp;
}
Date ElectionDay(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<11; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + days) % 7;
    int E = 0;
    if(result>1)
        E=1+7-result+2;
    else
        E=1+2-result;

    return Date(1, E, yr);

    // 1st tuesday after 1st monday in november
    // put your code here
}

Date VeteransDay(int yr)
{    // Nov 11

    Date temp(11, 11, yr);
    return temp;

}

Date thanksgiving(int yr)
{
    int leap = Date::isLeap(yr);
    int day = 0, days = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<11; i++)
        days += daysInMonth[leap][i];
    int result = (Date::get_day_code(yr) + days) % 7;
    int T = 0;
    if(result>4)
        T=1+7*3+7-result+4;
    else
        T=1+7*3+4-result;

    return Date(11, T, yr);



    // function that returns a Date object which is the date for Thanksgiving of the year yr
    //  the fourth thursday of Novemeber


    // put your code here
}

Date xmas(int yr)
{
    return Date(12, 25, yr);
}
```

Here i updated my algorithms, it took me a while to figure these out. 
Anyone here has a mathematics major? Is there a general formula for calculating all these dates?

Comment: wow! you should probably start by getting something small to work first..

Comment: you have like the same solution repeated all over: given a certain month and order (1st, 2nd, last?) and a day of the week, you want to get the exact date. try to solve for a simple case in which you don't have to concert about leap years, etc...

Comment: Too much code here. Please narrow it down to only those parts that you have a problem with. And please note we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I post the correct answer, and you will need all of those codes to figure out what i am asking for. All I wanna know is there a general algorithm for calculating these holidays.